# A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID xxxx

Tags: unit-test, visual-workflow, failing-tests

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, The record couldn’t be saved
>   because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute
>   the flow with version ID 301R0000000DGbx. Flow error messages: **An
>   unhandled fault has occurred in this flow**
> An unhandled fault
>   has occurred while processing the flow.  Please contact your system
>   administrator for more information.  Contact your administrator for
>   help.: []

While running all the test classes , we are getting the following error.

How to approach the issue without using Workbench to find out the flow id.

Comment: Not sure why you would not want to use workbench but without it and unless you know the flow causing it it would be a process of elimination along with reviewing the debug logs

Comment: @Eric- There is a client  restriction on the usage

Comment: Well. Tell them it will take you hours and hours to find it without workbench and a few minutes with. If they care about cost they may enable it. But if not have fun. I do not envy your task

Comment: Provided I got the Flow . What would be my approach . I could see API mismatch mentioned as solution somewhere.

Comment: Review the error email and flow then resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Download the complete Setup Audit Trail and search for the version id (301R0000000DGbx in your case). There you will find the translation of the version id to the human readable name of the process. Inspect it in Process Builder and hopefully you will find a clue.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the workbench, I would determine which test class is throwing the error, then run that test class by itself and review the debug log.

Within the debug log, you will see the same error right after the culprit Process is ran. The debug log will give you the name of the Process so you can either deactivate it or determine the error within the Process. Most likely, the Process is trying to set a value using a variable that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to identify the "Offending" flow or process builder when the generic flow error is shown or when you get the error in a unit test in Salesforce Classic, use the Boostr for Salesforce Chrome Extension. When this error is shown, the extension adds a "View Offending Process Builder or Flow" link that opens the flow designer with the offending process builder or flow.

[image]

Clicking "View Offending Process Builder or Flow" opens the Flow Designer with the Flow Version Id to show the process builder or flow that caused the error.

[image]

Note: Even though the flow designer is opened, a process builder may actually be causing the issue. A process builder opens successfully in the flow designer because under the hood it really is a flow.

I originally added this enhancement because when you don't receive the Flow error email, it's challenging to determine the offending flow or process builder, especially if there are many of them.